# Two commands won't work with drush

Tags: drush

I try to run typical commands like `drush cc all` or `drush pm-uninstall` while in the folder of my local site (in my pc, win 7 sp3), and yet I get error say:

> 1. "'mode' is not recognized as..."
> 2. "There were no modules that could be uninstalled".

[image]

I've never seen the first error in windows 7, and I do have modules to uninstall, so why won't I see a list? thanks,

Comment: try this syntax `drush pm-uninstall module_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this comment https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/58#issuecomment-23716869 it has something to do with your PATH variable. Fix it and the error should go away.

> Added C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\SysWOW64 to PATH in Environment
>   Variables.  Both errors gone the 'mode' one and the other one about
>   console window width.

Comment: Added this value to the variable path, and the 'mode' and width errors vanished, but I still get the wired error "There where no modules that could be uninstall"... But in fact I have many active modules so why can this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are running drush from the correct folder? What happens when you try 'drush status'?

Comment: Drush status gives me  a list of features such as Drupal version, site URI, Database driver, Database username, etc, so it runs fine... Drush cc all ran fine also (success), but when i run "Drush pm-uninstall" it tells me that there were no modules that could be uninstalled... Maybe it's because I didn't insert any modules at () ?... I just wanted a list to know how to write down the name of modules correctly in Drush.